# Sort order a Table by name and version SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have the following table, `table_1` which I need to order it by two columns:

```
Name     |   Version   |   Age   |   Registration_Date
-----------------------------------------------
A_x      |      1      |   35    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      1      |   12    |   20/1/2019
A_x      |      2      |   34    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      2      |   35    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      1      |   54    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      1      |   65    |   20/1/2019
F_x      |      1      |   11    |   20/1/2019
F_y      |      1      |   22    |   20/1/2019
E_y      |      1      |   27    |   20/1/2019
E_x      |      1      |   89    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      2      |   99    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      2      |   77    |   20/1/2019
```

and I need it to be sorted by the name and version, like this:

```
Name     |   Version   |   Age   |   Registration_Date
-----------------------------------------------
A_x      |      1      |   35    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      1      |   12    |   20/1/2019
A_x      |      2      |   34    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      2      |   35    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      1      |   54    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      1      |   65    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      2      |   99    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      2      |   77    |   20/1/2019
E_y      |      1      |   27    |   20/1/2019
E_x      |      1      |   89    |   20/1/2019
F_x      |      1      |   11    |   20/1/2019
F_y      |      1      |   22    |   20/1/2019
```

Here is what I'm doing ..

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 order by lower(Name), Version desc;
```

but still getting this output:

```
Name     |   Version   |   Age   |   Registration_Date
-----------------------------------------------
A_x      |      1      |   35    |   20/1/2019
A_x      |      2      |   34    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      1      |   12    |   20/1/2019
A_y      |      2      |   35    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      1      |   54    |   20/1/2019
C_x      |      2      |   99    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      1      |   65    |   20/1/2019
C_y      |      2      |   77    |   20/1/2019
E_x      |      1      |   89    |   20/1/2019
E_y      |      1      |   27    |   20/1/2019
F_x      |      1      |   11    |   20/1/2019
F_y      |      1      |   22    |   20/1/2019
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample data that you posted you need first to order by the part of the name up to the underscore:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
order by lower(left(Name, charindex('_', name))), Version, lower(Name);
```

or if it is always only 1 char before the underscore:

```
SELECT * FROM table_1 
order by lower(left(Name, 1)), Version, lower(Name);
```

I use `lower()` only because you have it in your code. If it is not needed you can remove it.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=96d6fe13a42368031c2211cd384665e8).
Results:

```
> Name | Version | Age | Registration_Date
> :--- | ------: | --: | :----------------
> A_x  |       1 |  35 | 20/1/2019        
> A_y  |       1 |  12 | 20/1/2019        
> A_x  |       2 |  34 | 20/1/2019        
> A_y  |       2 |  35 | 20/1/2019        
> C_x  |       1 |  54 | 20/1/2019        
> C_y  |       1 |  65 | 20/1/2019        
> C_x  |       2 |  99 | 20/1/2019        
> C_y  |       2 |  77 | 20/1/2019        
> E_x  |       1 |  89 | 20/1/2019        
> E_y  |       1 |  27 | 20/1/2019        
> F_x  |       1 |  11 | 20/1/2019        
> F_y  |       1 |  22 | 20/1/2019
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, the problem is that the name of the columns could be something else like `anything.X_test` or `anything_x_test` .. not alwaus `A_x`

Comment: This is why i say *for the sample data that you posted*.  This code answers the question as you posted it.

Comment: My 1st query should work for any name if what you are looking for is the part up to the underscore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the order by for `Name` column. Try like:

```
...ORDER BY SUBSTRING(Name, 1, 1),Version,SUBSTRING(Name, 3, 1)
```